# Check if players have received apprequest

Tags: c#, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-unity-sdk

I want to show players that they have received an apprequest from their friends.

I can do this already with this code:

```
FB.API("/me/apprequests", HttpMethod.GET, ResponseCallBack);
```

and repeat that every x seconds. But this will create a lot of traffic when the game gets more popular.

Is there another way to achieve this?
I searched for it but could not find any thing.

The game is written for android with unity in c#.

Comment: Why would you do that every second?

Comment: why would you even need to know if someone received the request? what is the use case?

Comment: Ow sorry I was forget to say I use apprequest to send gameroom ID so the player can join his friends room to play with or against him. So that must happen frequently, if it happens every minute people won't like it and won't wait for so long.

Comment: sounds weird, why not use node.js with socket.io? (just one quick idea). i don´t think apprequests are the right way to do this.

Comment: I am willing to invest my time in node.js and socket.io (no experience with it) if it is possible to do what I am willing to do. So when player A sends invite to friend B, Friends B receives realtime the invite with the needed information to join the game.

Comment: that is exactly where websockets are useful. apprequests are the wrong way to implement realtime stuff...

Comment: or take a look at firebase > realtime database

Comment: Okey thank you verry much @luschn for all your help. Is it possible to flag your comment as answer?

Comment: well, it´s not really an answer...but i will create one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not use apprequests for realtime stuff, better use **Websockets** (Node.js + Socket.io) or **Firebase** (Realtime Database) for those kind of things. Apprequests are more like "fire and forget" notifications.